# "The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'stream' module" when using Auth.js for email authentication

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

My NextJS 14 project is using Auth.js for passwordless email authentication and Prisma as the ORM for a Postgres db. I have my **auth.config.ts** set up like this:

```
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google"
import Email from "next-auth/providers/email"
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"

export default {
    providers: [
        Email({
            server: {
                host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
                port: Number(process.env.SMTP_PORT),
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
                    pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
                },
            },
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        }),
        Google({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

This config, I then call in **auth.ts** thus:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import authConfig from "@/auth.config"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter"
import { db } from "@/lib/db"

export const {
    handlers: { GET, POST },
    auth,
} = NextAuth({
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
    session: { strategy: "jwt" },
    ...authConfig,
})
```

My **api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts** is the tiniest:

```
export { GET, POST } from "@/auth"
```

With this setup, I am able to perform my Google login without hiccups. But the email part is giving me the edge runtime error. This bit in the **auth.config.ts**:

```
Email({
            server: {
                host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
                port: Number(process.env.SMTP_PORT),
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
                    pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
                },
            },
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        }),
```

I am just following the official documentation over at https://authjs.dev/getting-started/providers/email-tutorial! I understand that Prisma doesn’t work with Edge runtime, which is why I abstracted the providers into a separate config. What else is missing? I cannot change my ORM.